# Do browsers prefer leaner JS bundles?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I'm working in an MVC application that has about 10 BIG JavaScript libraries (jquery, modernizr, knockout, flot, bootstrap...), about 30 jQuery plugins and each view (hundreds of them) has it's own corresponding Javascript file.

The default MVC4 bundling is used, but all these JavaScript files are packaged in two bundles; one containing all the plugins and libraries, and one for the view specific files. And these two bundles are loaded on EVERY page, regardless if needed or not.

Now, they're loaded only the first time the user opens the application, but even minified the two are about 300 KB (way more raw), and the bulk of that code is very specific to certain pages.

**So, is it better for the browsers to have 2 giant bundles, or to create "smarter" and lighter bundles specific to pages, but have more of them?** The browser would cache them regardless first time they're opened, but is there any performance benefit to having less javascript loaded per page vs having all of it loaded on every page?

Answer (score 0):

If there's any chance of not needing them for a session then it would make sense to split them into smaller bundles.  Obviously any bytes that you don't have to send are good bytes ;)

You're right about the caching somewhat eliminating this problem as once you need it once it can be cached, but if, for example, you have a calendar page and a news page, it's conceivable that someone could not care at all about the calendar and so it wouldn't make sense to load it.

That said, you can probably go overboard on splitting things up and the overhead caused by creating each new request will add up to more than you save by not loading larger libraries all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the files is irrelevant to a browser on its own, size of the page as a whole is relevant to the user's computer, it will impact processor, network and memory (where the 3 mentioned components performance will somewhat depend on the browser used).

Many small files will probably provide a better response on slow clients because the file downloads and is executed, vs. waiting to download a big file (waiting for memory to be allocated to read the file) and the executing the scripts.

People will probably suggest to go easy on the scripts and plugins if you want a leaner web application.

Answer (score 0):

Concepts like image sprites and JS bundling are inventions due to the goal of minimising HTTP requests. Each HTTP request has an overhead and can result in bottlenecks, so it's better to have one big bundle than many small bundles.

Having said that, as Grdaneault said, you don't want users to load JS that they won't use.

So the best approach would be to bundle all the common stuff into one, then do separate bundles for uncommon stuff. Possibly bundle per view, depends on your structure. But don't let your bundles overlap (e.g. bundle A has file A & B, bundle B has file A & C), as this will result in duplicate loading.

Though 30 plugins, wow. The initial load is just one of the many issues to sort out.  Think carefully as to whether you need them all - not everyone will have an environment that's as performant as you hopefully do!